# Get subset of pandas DataFrame using dynamic expression including the shift method

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, dataframe, slice

I have this `pandas` dataframe:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame([[43.97, 43.97, 43.75, 43.94],
   ...:                    [43.97, 44.25, 43.97, 44.25],
   ...:                    [44.22, 44.38, 44.12, 44.34],
   ...:                    [44.41, 44.84, 44.38, 44.81],
   ...:                    [44.97, 45.09, 44.47, 45.00],
   ...:                    [44.97, 45.06, 44.72, 44.97],
   ...:                    [44.97, 45.12, 44.91, 44.97]],
   ...:                   columns=['O', 'H', 'L', 'C'])
```

Thanks to @JoeKington I'm able to get a subset of it using this expression:

```
In [3]: values = df[(df.C > df.H.shift(2)) & (df.H > df.H.shift(1))]

In [4]: print values
       O      H      L      C
2  44.22  44.38  44.12  44.34
3  44.41  44.84  44.38  44.81
4  44.97  45.09  44.47  45.00
```

What I want to do is take a string of comparisons like:

`C0 > L0 AND L0 > H2 AND H2 > L1 AND L1 > L2` or
`H0 > C0 AND C0 > H1 AND H1 > C1 AND C1 > H2 AND H2 > L1 AND L1 > L2`

And transform them into something that can be used to slice/filter/query the dataframe.  I have no problem taking one of those strings and creating a string that looks like this.

`(df.C > df.L) & (df.L > df.H.shift(2)) & (df.H.shift(2) > df.L.shift(1)) & (df.L.shift(1) > df.L.shift(2))`

Let's call this string *condition*.  Now if I want to use it to return a subset of the array I cannot do the following because a string is not expected here.

```
values = df[condition]
```

I tried using the query method like this `values = df.query(condition)`, but I think the `shift` is causing it to fail because I get this error: `NotImplementedError: 'Call' nodes are not implemented`

I have read through the `pandas` documentation and searched for hours for a solution and have not found one.  I'm new to `python`, `pandas` and `numpy`. I would really appreciate any guidance.

Comment: Is it really that important to start from a string?  We can parse one, but wouldn't it be easier just to store a list of the columns and shifts you want and then loop over them?

Comment: @DSM - I'm open to any solution.  I just started from a string because I have them in a text file.

Comment: @DSM - I will be able to take your input and use it to solve my problem. Thanks for sharing and teaching me something tonight.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working from formulae in strings is generally a sign of a misstep, but if you've already got them, then we might as well use them.  Something like

```
s = "C0 > L0 AND L0 > H2 AND H2 > L1 AND L1 > L2"
s = s.replace(" AND ", " and ")
shifted_cols = sorted({term for term in s.split() if 
                       term[0].isalpha() and term.lower() not in {"and", "or"}})
cshifts = [(c, c[0], int(c[1:])) for c in shifted_cols]
df_shift = pd.DataFrame({col: df[base_col].shift(s) for col, base_col, s in cshifts})
df.loc[df_shift.eval(s)]
```

will give

```
>>> df.loc[df_shift.eval(s)]
       O      H      L      C
3  44.41  44.84  44.38  44.81
```

---

This works because we discover the shifted columns we need:

```
>>> shifted_cols
['C0', 'H2', 'L0', 'L1', 'L2']
```

Break this up into column + shift (here the columns are all one-letter so I did the simplest thing possible, which isn't very robust, but switching to something more clever is trivial):

```
>>> cshifts
[('C0', 'C', 0), ('H2', 'H', 2), ('L0', 'L', 0), ('L1', 'L', 1), ('L2', 'L', 2)]
```

Then we construct a temporary dataframe that we can evaluate our string on:

```
>>> df_shift
      C0     H2     L0     L1     L2
0  43.94    NaN  43.75    NaN    NaN
1  44.25    NaN  43.97  43.75    NaN
2  44.34  43.97  44.12  43.97  43.75
3  44.81  44.25  44.38  44.12  43.97
4  45.00  44.38  44.47  44.38  44.12
5  44.97  44.84  44.72  44.47  44.38
6  44.97  45.09  44.91  44.72  44.47
>>> df_shift.eval(s)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
5    False
6    False
dtype: bool
```

which we finally use to index into our original frame.